Python - Inner for loop does not save updated state from outer loop into list
I have a 2d list storing an 8x8 grid.
The nested for loop sets the coordinates for each square as (left, upper, right, lower).
The top-left corner of a square is (curr-x, curr-y). These are increased by a set distance with every new column and row respectively.
Problem: While the inner loop does receive the updated row height (after moving down a row), this value is not actually saved correctly into the array.
Instead, every square in every row saves the same starting height (start_y).
grid = [[]] * 8
vertical_distance = 35 # for one square
horizontal_distance = 30 # for one square

curr_x = start_x
curr_y = start_y

for row in range(8):
    for col in range(8):
        grid[row].append((curr_x, curr_y, curr_x + horizontal_distance, curr_y + vertical_distance))
        curr_x += horizontal_distance  # move right to next column

    curr_x = start_x                   # reset at left hand side for each new row
    curr_y += vertical_distance        # move down to next row

Inside the nested for loop, I print out the curr_x and curr_y variables.
These are correctly updated, with curr_y incremented for the new row.
I then immediately print out the new grid row, but the top y-value is always set to start_y, not curr_y.
for row in range(8):
        for col in range(8):
            grid[row].append((curr_x, curr_y, curr_x + horizontal_distance, curr_y + vertical_distance))
            print("\ncurr-x: {}, curr-y: {}".format(curr_x, curr_y))
            print(grid[row][col])
            curr_x += horizontal_distance # move right to next column

        curr_x = start_x # reset at left hand side for each new row
        curr_y += vertical_distance # move down to next row

=== EXAMPLE ===
ROW 1:
curr_x: 32.5, curr_y: **40.0**

(32.5, **40.0**, 62.5, 75.0)

ROW 2:
curr_x: 32.5, curr_y: **75.0**

(32.5, **40.0**, 62.5, 75.0)


Welcome to Stack Overflow! grid = [[]] * 8 will create an array with 8 references to the same list (if you change one, you change all of them). Do a=[[] for _ in range(8)] instead.
